# Android relativelayout to right of programmaticaly

Tags: android, layout

I have Relative layout :

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/show_photo_details_comment_who_liked"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/show_photo_details_comment_who_liked_star"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/photo_rate_on" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and  want to add few text views into it, and I want to place them right next to ImageView...

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.show_photo_details_comment_who_liked_star);

RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.show_photo_details_comment_who_liked);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams youParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
youParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
youParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, img.getId() );
youParam.setMargins(10,0,0,0);

TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tv.setLayoutParams(youParam);
tv.setText( getString( R.string.who_liked_you ) );
tv.setTextColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.green) );

rl.addView(tv);

youParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv.getId());
youParam.setMargins(0,0,0,0);

tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tv.setLayoutParams(youParam);
tv.setText( "," );
tv.setTextColor( Color.BLACK );


rl.addView(tv);
```

But all theese views will show up in left top corner. Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing the same `LayoutParams` object with all views, so they end up using the same layout params. See [May I reuse LayoutPrams with ViewGroup.addView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10432656/3959454).

Also after you fix this, you should assign some id to the first `TextView` (via `setId()`) because otherwise the two TextViews have the same id `-1`, and `RelativeLayout` may choose the wrong one of them when processing this:

```
youParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv.getId());
```

**UPDATE**
Actually do you really need to do all this programmatically? Consider adding all these views to the layout XML with `android:visibility="gone"` and unhiding them when needed.